# Combination of inner join and ansi

Tags: sql

I am trying to Combine 2 tables By their primary key but also add a select count of one table in addition. I tried

```
Select a.ram as ram1, b.ram as ram2 from a,b
```

Now I want to add count(*)  of b which
Is not working.

```
Select
(Select count(*) from b inner join a on a.ram=b.ram as numberbids),
A.ram as ram1, b.ram as ram2 from a,b;
```

Is giving me the correct columns but counts all the bids of b in total and not in relation to the Rams.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

I got:
table a:

```
ram
x
y
```

table b:

```
z
ram
bids
```

I want:

```
ram1   ram2   numberofbids
```

I hope this helps? I am very new to SQL

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Hornlui2 Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Where confusing subject. Inner joins are ANSI SQL.

Comment: i tried to add the data sample

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.ram,b.ram,count(*) as numberbids
from b inner join a on a.xy=b.xy
group by a.ram,b.ram
```

In case you don't want to do `INNER JOIN`, you want a cross product then use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select a.ram,b.ram,count(*) as numberbids
from b cross join a
group by a.ram,b.ram
```

Comment: The problem is that the output for a.ram and b.ram then is the same but is actually supposed to be different. WIth my Select a.ram as ram1, b.ram as ram2 from a,b i get the right, different outputs for a.ram and b.ram but cant set it in relation to the count

Comment: @Hornlui2 I guess `xy` is the FK. So change the join to `a.xy=b.xy`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: no, ram is the FK.  xy ist a missleading sorry, changed it

Comment: @Hornlui2 Then you will get only same values for both a.ram and b.ram or else you will have to do cross join.

Comment: @Hornlui2 Updated my answer, do check it and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: hm Thank you very much but thats still does not get me the output i want. i am looking for the combinations of objects (mentioned by their ram1 and ram2 from each table) that have the same number of bids. The cross join is giving all the possibilities but i only need the corresponding ones

Comment: @Hornlui2 If you join only same ram then when you select from both it will be same, right?

Comment: right but i am combining the objects and not their names(ram1/2). i need to finde the combinations of objects that have the same number of bids and then give out theis rams:

Comment: ram1:1,1,2
ram2:2,5,5
NumberBids: 2,2,2
because 1+2,1+5,2+5 have all the same number of bids#

Comment: ok so sorry i think my explanation (english) ist not very good.. i am looking for objects with the same count of bids. to give out the two of them im one row, the heahline is ram1  and ram2. so object one and two. but i dont know how to join for "having the same amount of bids" and giving out the 2 names at one time

Comment: i asked my question here again http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157618/combination-of-two-objects-in-one-row-by-similarity